# Can I get data from appsettings.json in a Razor .cshtml component with rendered html?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am rendering a HTML body with the `RenderBody()` method.

This is the code I am using:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@using Signumid.ESignLiteShop.Data.Models
@namespace Signumid.ESignLiteShop.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <base href="~/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="Signumid.ESignLiteShop.styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/open-sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" r
               ender-mode="ServerPrerendered"/>

    <title>eSign-Lite Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
```

In this line here I tried adding the `appsettings` config and tried getting it into the HTML, but this did not work. If I include this line of code then the `@RenderBody()` method cannot be executed, it throws an error.

```
@{

        public static IOptions<ShopAppSettings> _config = null!;
}
```

This is the rest of the body of the HTML that I try to render. Here I would like to get a value from `appsettings` and to look something like this:

`newPackageOneCardImg.src = "[here I would like to have data from appsettings]";`

```
@RenderBody()
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

<script src="./_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="./_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
<script>

"use strict";
function purchaseComplete() {
    window.postMessage({ type: "SIGNATOR_BILLING_PURCHASE_COMPLETED" }, "*");
    //TODO: Add tooltip
}
function purchaseClosed() {
    //TODO: Add tooltip 
}
var BillingComponent = (function () {
    function BillingComponent(mobilePhone, organizationId) {
        this.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
    }
    BillingComponent.prototype.buyAndOpenCheckout = function (productId, quantity) {
        window.Paddle.Checkout.open({
            product: productId,
            passthrough: { phoneNumber: this.mobilePhone, organizationId: this.organizationId },
            quantity: quantity,
            allowQuantity: false,
            disableLogout: true,
            successCallback: purchaseComplete,
            closeCallback: purchaseClosed,
        });
    };
    BillingComponent.prototype.renderBillingModal = function () {
        var _this = this;
        document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
        var getDrawerElement = document.getElementById("shop-billing-container");
        //create modal content div element
        var modalContent = document.createElement("div");
        modalContent.classList.add("billing-modal-content");
        var modalContentBodyContent = document.createElement("div");
        modalContentBodyContent.classList.add("billing-modal-content-body-content");
        //create new package
        //package ONE
        var newPackageOneCard = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageOneCard.classList.add("signator-billing-package-card");
        newPackageOneCard.onclick = function () { return _this.buyAndOpenCheckout("32227"); };
        var newPackageOneCardImgBox = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageOneCardImgBox.classList.add("signatorCardImgBox");
        var newPackageOneCardImg = document.createElement("img");
        newPackageOneCardImg.classList.add("signator-package-image");
        newPackageOneCardImg.src = "";
        var newPackageOneCardContentBox = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageOneCardContentBox.classList.add("signator-billing-package-card-content-box");
        var newPackageOneCardContentTitle = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageOneCardContentTitle.classList.add("signator-billing-package-card-h3");
        newPackageOneCardContentTitle.textContent = "10 credits";
        var newPackageOneCardContentTitleTwo = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageOneCardContentTitleTwo.classList.add("signator-billing-package-card-h2");
        newPackageOneCardContentTitleTwo.textContent =
            /*i18next.t("price_label")*/ "Price:" + @_config.Value.Test;
        var newPackageOneCardContentBuyButton = document.createElement("a");
        newPackageOneCardContentBuyButton.classList.add("signator-billing-package-card-buy-button");
        newPackageOneCardContentBuyButton.textContent = "Buy";
        newPackageOneCardImgBox.appendChild(newPackageOneCardImg);
        newPackageOneCardContentBox.appendChild(newPackageOneCardContentTitle);
        newPackageOneCardContentBox.appendChild(newPackageOneCardContentTitleTwo);
        newPackageOneCardContentBox.appendChild(newPackageOneCardContentBuyButton);
        newPackageOneCard.appendChild(newPackageOneCardImgBox);
        newPackageOneCard.appendChild(newPackageOneCardContentBox);
        //package TWO
        var newPackageTwoCard = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageTwoCard.classList.add("signator-billing-package-card");
        newPackageTwoCard.onclick = function () { return _this.buyAndOpenCheckout("32228"); };
        var newPackageTwoCardImgBox = document.createElement("div");
        newPackageTwoCardImgBox.classList.add("signatorCardImgBox");
        var newPackageTwoCardImg = document.createElement("img");
        newPackageTwoCardImg.classList.add("signator-package-image");
        newPackageTwoCardImg.src =
        newPackageThreeCardContentBuyButton.textContent = "Buy";
        newPackageThreeCardImgBox.appendChild(newPackageThreeCardImg);
        newPackageThreeCardContentBox.appendChild(newPackageThreeCardContentTitle);
        newPackageThreeCardContentBox.appendChild(newPackageThreeCardContentTitleTwo);
        newPackageThreeCardContentBox.appendChild(newPackageThreeCardContentBuyButton);
        newPackageThreeCard.appendChild(newPackageThreeCardImgBox);
        newPackageThreeCard.appendChild(newPackageThreeCardContentBox);
        //create modal footer with button
        var modalContentFooter = document.createElement("div");
        modalContentFooter.classList.add("billing-modal-content-footer");
        modalContent.appendChild(modalContentBodyContent);
        modalContentBodyContent.appendChild(newPackageOneCard);
        modalContentBodyContent.appendChild(newPackageTwoCard);
        modalContentBodyContent.appendChild(newPackageThreeCard);
        modalContent.appendChild(modalContentFooter);
        if (getDrawerElement) {
            getDrawerElement.appendChild(modalContent);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var getDrawerElementAfterTimeout = document.getElementById("shop-billing-container");
                getDrawerElementAfterTimeout === null || getDrawerElementAfterTimeout === void 0 ? void 0 : getDrawerElementAfterTimeout.appendChild(modalContent);
            }, 500);
        }
    };
    return BillingComponent;
}());

window.signatorBilling =
    {
        ShowBillingModal: function (number, organizationId) {
             var x = new BillingComponent(number, organizationId);
             x.renderBillingModal();
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Paddle.Environment.set("sandbox");
Paddle.Setup({vendor:1234});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line of code in your program startup file,

```
builder.Services.Configure<ShopAppSettings>(builder.Configuration); //code may differ depending on your version of ASP.NET
```

Then, in the controller code (whatever the code uses the cshtml),

```
private readonly IOptions<ShopAppSettings> _options;    
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IOptions<ShopAppSettings> options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _options = options;
    }
```

Now, in the cshtml file,

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<ShopAppSettings> shopAppOptions
@{ 
    var options = shopAppOptions.Value;
}

newPackageOneCardImg.src = "@options.your_configs";
```

Comment: But I don't have a controller for the _Layout.cshtml component. I cannot inject it like that. That is my problem.

Comment: I even tried injecting it like this ``@inject IOptions<ShopAppSettings> shopAppOptions;``
And using it like this : ``@shopAppOptions.Value.Test``, but then the whole body does not render. When I stop there with the breakpoint, the value is there, but for some reason the body does not render.

Comment: If the value is there, the configuration is working. There might be something wrong with your page. Try to isolate the issue by removing the options code and see if the page still works.